# Bootstrap CSS & JSP

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

hope you're doing fine.
I am currently stuck with my Web App project. This is the context: I would like to code a Web App using J2E. There's a free template that I liked and thus I decided to download it. When starting to use it I notice the CSS isn't applied.
Instead of having  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfhNW.jpg), I have  [this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FYGZ.png)

However I do not see where the error is. The CSS & Bootstrap files should be visible in the JSP file and IntelliJ recognizes them. However I can't display these files (whether css or even pictures) that are referenced in "href".
Here's the [project structure and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0DCZ.png), maybe something's wrong there.

I'm used to HTML and to my understanding JSP isn't too different. Are the referencings different though?

Thanks in advance for any help you'll give,

Fares

Answer (score 1):

YES. 
Found the answer. Put resources in different folder than WEB-INF.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, your HTML file is inside the WEB-INF folder, for the  to work either remove the WEB-INF path

```
<link href='style/stylesheet.css'>
```

or move your HTML one folder up.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried removing the "WEB-INF" in the path, same result. I can't move my HTML one folder up since I'm already at the root of the "web" folder